# Django & Migrate Error: I can't migrate my project

Tags: django

I was trying to run a Django project which I got from someone else.
But I can't do the migration.
I came from a mobile app development background. So I'm quite new to this backend thing including Django.

Please have a look and help with this issue. Thank you

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/punreachrany/Desktop/MyProject/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/punreachrany/Desktop/MyProject/manage.py", line 18, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/Users/punreachrany/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/Users/punreachrany/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "/Users/punreachrany/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/Users/punreachrany/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "/Users/punreachrany/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
        import_module(entry)
      File "/Users/punreachrany/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
```

Comment: You haven't installed bootstrap4, so the project can't find it - use pip install and try again

Comment: as a general rule, start aligning both env checking the requirements.txt file the repo you got should have, otherwise you have to install all the package one by one (and they could be a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is a dependency you need to add. You can install it by running the below command before migrating.(This is a one time setup)

```
python -m pip install bootstrap4
```

Since you mentioned you got the project from someone else.In that case check if there is a file called `requirements.txt`.

If it exists, run the below command from that directory to install all the required dependencies.

```
Python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Anyway, how can we check what library we have to install in order to run a python/django project? Does it have any file that contains a list of libraries?

Comment: You can run **pip list** to check all the installed dependencies